# Using google maps api to render markers on Open cycle map (open street map)

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to use create markers using the google maps api to draw a route on an embeded open cycle map.

here is the progress:

http://embed.plnkr.co/yq9NudcYyTfCnVqe6MH0/index.html

I cannot seem to get the markers down.

something like this:

```
 var myLatLng = new.google.maps.LatLong(50.4261, -3.8401);
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: 'Hello World!'
  });
```

as per 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Any ideas??

Comment: @ MaM Yes, it is related to OSM...did you look at the progress link?  I am embedding OCM (branch of OSM) and using google maps toolkit to render the map tiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an excellent solution: http://www.mapsmarker.com/docs/how-to-install-the-plugin/

Great plugin and easy to construct, basically saved me a day of coding.